# Не взаимодействуют типы в return и внутри хука (React + TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Пытаюсь протипизировать return данного хука. Предполагаю, что всего могут быть 3 return'a, когда есть дата - остального нет, когда крутится лоадер – остального нет, когда выбрасывает ошибку – остального нет, но TS так не считает, вот получаю вот такую ошибку:

Type '{ data: ResponseDataType | null; isLoading: boolean; error: string | null; }' is not assignable to type '{ data: ResponseDataType; isLoading: false; error: null; } | { data: null; isLoading: true; error: null; } | { data: null; isLoading: false; error: string; }'.
Type '{ data: ResponseDataType | null; isLoading: boolean; error: string | null; }' is not assignable to type '{ data: null; isLoading: false; error: string; }'.
Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
Type 'ResponseDataType | null' is not assignable to type 'null'.
Type 'ResponseDataType' is not assignable to type 'null'.
Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'null'.ts(2322)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useFetch = <ResponseDataType extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  url: string
):
  | {
      data: ResponseDataType;
      isLoading: false;
      error: null;
    }
  | {
      data: null;
      isLoading: true;
      error: null;
    }
  | {
      data: null;
      isLoading: false;
      error: string;
    } => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<ResponseDataType | null>(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    axios
      .get<ResponseDataType>(url)
      .then((response) => setData(response.data))
      .then(() => console.log(data))
      .catch((err) => {
        if (axios.isAxiosError(err)) {
          setError(err.message);
        }
      })
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, [url]);

  return {
    data,
    isLoading,
    error,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы же описываете тип, а не все возможные значения. Попробуйте так:

```
export const useFetch = <ResponseDataType extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  url: string
): {
      data: ResponseDataType;
      isLoading: boolean;
      error: string;
    } => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<ResponseDataType>(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    axios
      .get<ResponseDataType>(url)
      .then((response) => setData(response.data))
      .then(() => console.log(data))
      .catch((err) => {
        if (axios.isAxiosError(err)) {
          setError(err.message);
        }
      })
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, [url]);

  return {
    data: data,
    isLoading: isLoading,
    error: error,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил вот так:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function useFetch<ResponseDataType extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  url: string
):
  | {
      data: null;
      isLoading: false;
      error: string;
    }
  | {
      data: null;
      isLoading: true;
      error: null;
    }
  | {
      data: ResponseDataType;
      isLoading: false;
      error: null;
    } {
  const [data, setData] = useState<ResponseDataType | null>(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    const callApi = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get<ResponseDataType>(url);
        setData(response.data);
      } catch (err) {
        if (axios.isAxiosError(err)) {
          setError(err.message);
        }
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    callApi();
  }, [url]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return {
      data: null,
      isLoading,
      error: null,
    };
  }
  if (error) {
    return {
      data: null,
      isLoading: false,
      error,
    };
  }
  return {
    data: data!,
    isLoading: false,
    error: null,
  };
}
```